# How could I align my output to the center?

Tags: c, for-loop, indexing, output, alignment

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int n ;
        printf("Input the number of rows: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        for(int i = 1; i <= n ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1 ; j <= i ; j++)
            {
                if(j == i + 1)
                {
                    break;
                }

                printf("%3d", j);
    
            }
            for(int  j = i - 1 ; j > 0; j--)
            {
                if(j == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                printf("%3d", j);
            }
            printf("\n");
            
        }
    }
```

Program session

```
Number of rows for this output n = 3

My output:   
            1
            1  2  1      
            1  2  3  2  1


Preferred output:   
                  1
               1  2  1      
            1  2  3  2  1
```

This here is an exercise where I have to print a pyramid of numbers where the central number of the pyramid is the number of the row. I understand the logic but as you can see I have not been able to fulfill the task successfully. Any tips?

Comment: By adding another loop to print the necesary spaces?

Comment: Any concrete and well explained idea would be appreciated

Comment: You can compute the number of spaces needed from `n` the total number or rows and `i` the current row number, and the `3` hard coded into `printf("%3d", j);`. That last line can be done as `printf("%*d", width, j);` where `width` is a variable or constant that can be used by the calculation. Alterntively, use `printf("%3c", ' ');` in the loop.

Comment: I am not quite getting it. Could you please provide me with a sample code ?

Comment: Please have an attempt to work out the calculation. Try it on paper, first writing down the number of spaces needed at the start of each row, and then figure out how that number can be computed. Giving you some code to copy/paste won't really help you.

Comment: I understand that and I am currently working to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @WeatherWane, you need to add logic to add extra spaces. If you notice carefully, number of spaces on each line(excluding padding you add with `%3d` is equal to `3 * (n - i))`. You can create a simple method like this to add spacing:

```c
void addSpaces(int N, int currentIndex, int padding) {
  for (int index = currentIndex; index < N; index++)
      for (int spaces = 0; spaces < padding; spaces++)
         printf(" ");
}
```

then you can call it from your first for loop like this:

```c
  for(int i = 1; i <= n ; i++)
    {
      addSpaces(n, i, 3);
      for(int j = 1 ; j <= i ; j++)
        {
           // ...
```

I tested it and it seems to align it correctly:

```
c-posts : $ ./a.out 
Input the number of rows: 5
              1
           1  2  1
        1  2  3  2  1
     1  2  3  4  3  2  1
  1  2  3  4  5  4  3  2  1
```